# PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY returns and breaks the app

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I am trying to use `RSA` to encrypt some stuff using `OpenSSL`.

```
RSA *rsaPubKey = RSA_new();
FILE *file;
file = fopen("PubKey.pem","r");

if(file){
    rsaPubKey = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, &rsaPubKey ,NULL,NULL);
}
.......... //some stuff 
return 0
```

After executing `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` the app is terminated with no errors. I have no clue what's wrong!!

Comment: Try assign to rsaPubKey 0 instead of RSA_new().

Comment: Are you sure that app is terminated right in/after PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY?

Comment: Of course it is terminated, that is the end of your program!

Comment: no lol there is some stuff after it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code in an old project:

```
BIO *bioPub = BIO_new_file(pubkeyPath, "r");
RSA *pubkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bioPub, NULL, NULL, NULL);
/* do some stuff */
RSA_free(pubkey);
BIO_free(bioPub);
```

Have you tried the following?

```
FILE *file = fopen("PubKey.pem","r");
RSA *rsaPubKey = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```